# CSS > Fixed footer transition: slide up, no animation? Why and how to solve... + JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an fixed footer with css. In the demo you can see my attempt. But i have a problem with the css3 transition. Basically i have an toggle that after click event must show the fixed-bar on bottom.

```
.footer {position: fixed; top: 100%}
.enabled .footer {top: auto; bottom: 0}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ItalianD3V/xzbK8/

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It seems to work... browser?

Comment: I want an slide up animation for the footer becose now it's just jump...witout any transition. But also the css3 is enabled  when i hover the element

Comment: I'm watching the transition when I click on the circle. Which browser / version are you using?

Comment: Try this:
http://jqueryui.com/addClass/
or jquery.animate()

Comment: CHrome latest stable buildI... updated the fiddle...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ySUKq/

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't transition because you're trying to transition the .footer element from top: 100% to top: auto. Browsers can't transition to or from 'auto'. You'll have to establish a specific value in the .share > .footer rule.

Comment: Yes, I had this figured out ... but how to fix?